# SFMC MobilePush login and logout case

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am dealing with multiple login situations regarding Salesforce Marketing Cloud MobilePush.
If anybody knows the answers to any of the questions below, it would be a huge help.
**1. Multiple user logging into an app on the same device**
In that case, does that register the same DeviceID to multiple contacts with different contact keys?
**2. When user logs out from the app**
When user logs out from the app, the app should not send any messages to that user. How does Marketing Cloud usually process this? Does it set the contact's optin status as opt-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple users is not a supported use case.  Last-in-wins for `Contact Key`.  Logout, similarly, is not currently (20220126) supported.

Logout can be implemented by your application by clearing `Attributes`, removing `Tags` and setting the `Contact Key` to some unique value.  DO NOT REUSE CONTACT KEYS like "logged out."  Instead, create a unique GUID for the installation, retain it, and set that as the "anonymous" ContactKey when you want to log the user out.  You might also consider using the `delay registration until contact key is set` feature if you do not intend on sending push notifications (or using other features of Marketing Cloud Push) when the user is unknown.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bill! I have two additional questions regarding your answer. (1) I am wondering why it is not recommended to reuse contact keys like "logged out". According to my theory, when users log out from the app and SFMC receives their different device IDs under the same contact key value (ex. LOGOUT), that contact with multiple device IDs can be managed through exclusion list and it seems like there will be no issue. Is there additional consideration or issue?

Comment: (2) Also, as you said that logout can be implemented by your application by clearing Attributes, is it possible to also clear Device ID values along with other Attributes from the logged-out contact?

Comment: `DeviceID` should be treated like an (poorly named) `InstallationID` and will remain unchanged for the life of the application installation.

Comment: @BillMote How can we implement `delay registration until contact key is set` in iOS ?

Comment: The same way as Android.